# How can I accurately benchmark the time it takes to load a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, benchmarking

I want to benchmark the time it takes to load a module (a find_by_id(234) call).

Also, how can I track the time it takes to load a page, I know I get this information when I run rails server, but this is in debug mode, I want production speed benchmarks, possible?

Answer (score 32):

For a quick check, I would highly recommend checking out [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/index.html).

An example would be:

```
require "benchmark"

time = Benchmark.measure do
  a.find_by_id(234)
end
puts time
```

However for production level benchmarking, I would check out [New Relic.](http://newrelic.com/) They offer unbelievable benchmarking on nearly everything you could think of.

They have a free developer mode here :

http://support.newrelic.com/kb/docs/developer-mode

Answer (score 4):

You can use this gem:
https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/benchmark_methods

No more code like this:

```
t = Time.now
user.calculate_report
puts Time.now - t
```

Now you can do:

```
benchmark :calculate_report # in class
```

And just call your method

```
user.calculate_report
```

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend that you read the [Rails Guide on Performance Testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.0.0/performance_testing.html). It's a pretty good overview of what's available within rails. It's great if you want automated tests where you can make code changes and see instant results.

For production server benchmarking, [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/) probably does everything you'd want.