# Which is efficient either before_filter or an if check using params[:action]?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Which is more efficient, Case I or II?

Case I:

```
before_filter :validator, only: :test1
before_filter :parser, only: :test2

def test1
  <some code>
end

def test2
  <some code>
end

private

  def validator
    <condition1>
  end

  def parser
    <condition2>
  end
```

Case II:

```
before_filter :validator

def test1
  <some code>
end

def test2
  <some code>
end

private

  def validator
    if params[:action] == 'test1'
      <condition1>
    end

    if params[:action] == 'test2'
      <condition2>
    end
  end
```

Comment: efficiency-wise, there should be no noticeable difference. It's readability/maintainability that you should care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Case 1 is more efficient, but not because it runs more quickly. You can [benchmark them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5575403/525478) to be sure, but they almost certainly have very similar resource requirements.

The reason #1 is more efficient is because it reduces developer strain. For example, it more obviously expresses your intent. It can grow more organically, and it is much easier to write tests for. The complexity added by case 2 will negatively impact the project by making testing and long-term maintenance more difficult.

Comment: easier to write tests? It's a `before_action` in both cases. Have fun writing  tests for those :)

Comment: Much easier, yes. In case 2, one must establish more state in order to test the validator method. Testing the validator and parser methods separately will lead to less complicated setup, overall. It should be enough to test the methods independently, and verify that the methods are called when the action is hit (if desired). This also improves the test's ability to document the code.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you appear to have written a very similar opinion in the comments as I was writing this answer...

Comment: Maybe I should have said, easier to write informative, specific, and less complicated tests....

Comment: Yes, I agree more with this version of the statement :)